# Training embedding layers in neural networks with missing data

Tags: python, keras

I have a neural network that I want to train, with keras.
This network has as a first layer an embedding layer, called `E`, that maps a categorical feature into vectors.

Then the output of this embedding layer is mapped to another layer, that we will call `L`.

However some times, the value of this feature may be missed. 
So I would like to:

- In the prediction phase, when the value for the feature is missed to project from `E` to `L` the average of the feature-vector representations.
- In the training phase, not to update the weights for the  feature-vector representations when an input for this value is missing.

Is it possible to do this task with eras?

---

Edit

To be more precise, my model is as follows: I have two categorical inputs that then are

```
model_left = Sequential()
model_left.add(Embedding(FirstCategorical_count, 60, input_length=1))
model_right = Sequential()
model_right.add(Embedding(SecondCategorical_count, 60, input_length=1))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([model_left, model_right], mode='concat'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

where `FirstCategorical_count` and `SecondCategorical_count` are the vocabulary size of the two inputs. Both the inputs might be missing, or none of them, or only one.

Comment: By the average you mean average of feature vectors from other words in a sequence?

Comment: @marcin yes exactly

Comment: This is a really harsh problem. Could you provide more details on further layers?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, something like the edit